# Prove the following situation using Arzelà-Ascoli theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R^m}$ be open and $(f_n)$ an equicontinuous sequence of functions that converges pointwise in $\Omega$. Then $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega$.

So one of the versions of the theorem that I've got is the following

Let $\Omega$ be a open set of $R^{m}$, and $\{f_n\}$, $f_n:\Omega \to R^{l}$ a sequence of continous functions in $\Omega$ (not necesarilly bounded) equicontinous and pointwise bounded. Then there exists a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ that converges uniformly in each compact subset of $\Omega$.

But the thing is How can I cover all the hypotheses and ensure that the subsequence is the whole sequence $(f_n)$? I think that there is happening the same problem as here [How to use Arzelà-Ascoli theorem in this situation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1438366/how-to-use-arzel%C3%A0-ascoli-theorem-in-this-situation) right ?

Thanks a lot in advance I appreciate your help :)

My approach using @Ian's criterion:

We pick a subsequence of $(f_n)$, let say $(f_{n_k})$, then we get that $(f_{n_k})$ is equicontinuous and it converges pointwise to $f$, now since this happens we get:

$$|f_{n_k}-f(x)|<\epsilon \Rightarrow f(x)-\epsilon<f_{n_k}<f(x)+\epsilon$$

Then we only take the ball of radius $f_{n_k}<f(x)+\epsilon$ and with center at $0$, so we get by A-A theorem that $f_{n_k}$ has a subsequence that converges in each compact of $\Omega$, therefore by the criterion given by @Ian we are done.

The only thing I am unsure of is the radius of the ball , **Am I right in the above proof?**

**And How do I prove that the limit should be continuous ?**

Comment: A useful fact: if you have a sequence $x_n$ of real numbers such that every subsequence $x_{n_k}$ has a further subsequence $x_{n_{k_\ell}}$ which converges to $x$ (and $x$ doesn't depend on the subsequence) then $x_n$ converges to $x$. You can apply this to $x_n=\| f_n - f \|_\infty$ (where $f$ is the pointwise limit), $x=0$.

Comment: Right but the theorem only ensures a sequence not every sequence :)

Comment: Strictly speaking, yes. But consider the following: define $x_n$ as I said. Let $x_{n_k}$ be an arbitrary subsequence of $x_n$. Does it satisfy the hypotheses of Arzela-Ascoli? If so, then it has a subsequence $x_{n_{k_\ell}}$ which converges to zero. Now use the result I stated.

Comment: Well the only thing I need to check then is that the arbitrary sequence is pointwise bounded right?

Comment: Also equicontinuous. But you get these basically "for free" from the original sequence

Comment: Yes jajaj, but then what do you think about the linked question I have posted ?

Comment: The subsequence aspect is handled the same way, you just have to check that the monotonicity gets you the boundedness/equicontinuity you need.

Comment: jajaj right but that is the question :)

Comment: The easiest way to get the equicontinuity in the situation of the other question is to show that the sequence converges uniformly (by Dini's theorem). Yes, that kind of defeats the purpose, but I have a hard time thinking of sane ways to show equicontinuity in a different way.

Comment: Ok @DanielFischer :) I appreciate that a lot :), and What do you think about this one?, Can you provide an answer using only Arzelá-Ascoli?

Comment: You can't use literally "only Ascoli-Arzelà", you also need some other tools or theorems. [This criterion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/510813) - already mentioned by Ian - is the standard tool to show the convergence of the full sequence in situations like this.

Comment: Ok, but Is that criterion useful in the other question?, Well is because with the things said by @Ian this problem is almost done I only have to verify the pointwise bound but I am don't know it that will be difficult or not jajajaja

Comment: I am back, just a queston for @Ian , Why do I have to check equicontinuity of $||f_n-f||_u$? Because this is a sequence of numbers not of functions, I think you meant a subsequence of $(f_n)$ right?

Comment: @user162343 My phrasing was imprecise; I meant "if $n_k$ is an arbitrary subsequence of $n$, is $f_{n_k}$ pointwise bounded and equicontinuous? If so, then $x_{n_k}$ has a further subsequence which goes to zero, hence..."

Comment: Well Is because what I was understanding is that, ok I have the sequence $(f_n)$, so by the criterion you gave I have to check equicontinuity of $f_{n_k}$ and pointwise bounded, so then I get by Arzelà-Ascoli that this subsequence has a subsequence that converges in every compact set, therefore invoking your criterion I get that the whole sequence converges :) right?

Comment: @DanielFischer Have you found something for the other question using A-A?

Comment: I have edited my post, what do you think about it?

Comment: Do I have to ask this question in another post to get help?

Comment: @user162343: I don't get your problem. $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise. It is trivially pointwise bounded, so does any subsequence of $f_n$.

Comment: Right :) but What I want to know is that if the above proof is well writed and performed or there is something wrong or missing in my math :)

Comment: @user162343: It is okay. If you want to be pedantic, the bound for $f_{n_k}(x)$ is: $\max\{ |f(x)| + \epsilon, |f_{n_1}(x)|, \dotsc, |f_{n_{k_0}}(x)| \}$ for some $k_0\in\mathbb N$ depending on $x$ and $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ok :) thnks for your verification :), Now what do you think about this one http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1439619/show-that-the-set-mathcal-l-is-closed, Thnsk in advance :)